# Select * from table where columns contain a keyword

Tags: php, mysql

My Query
    SELECT * 
    from  users 
    where  user_id='$keyword' 
        OR username='$keyword' 
        OR email='$keyword' 
        OR skype='$keyword' 
        OR balance='$keyword' 
        OR spent='$keyword' 
        OR status='$keyword' 
        OR created='$keyword' 
        OR last_auth='$keyword'

Problem

Returning random rows

Comment: well - with what keyword do you call it and what "random rows" are displayed?

Comment: Well to start with, how many of these columns are strings (VARCHAR, CHAR, TEXT)? and how many are numbers or dates/datetimes? ie. If `balance` is a number, what's the point in testing to see if it matches a `$keyword` string?

Comment: "like" keyword in mysql can solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LIKE instead of trying to get the exact value.

```
SELECT * from  users where user_id LIKE '%$keyword' OR username LIKE '%$keyword%' OR email LIKE '%$keyword%' OR skype LIKE '%$keyword%' OR balance LIKE '%$keyword%' OR spent LIKE '%$keyword%' OR status LIKE '%$keyword%' OR created LIKE '%$keyword%' OR last_auth LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

If you are using LIKE on a number field use:

```
CAST(user_id AS CHAR) LIKE '%keyword%'
```